# systemdのユニットにおけるrequiresが機能してないように見えます

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

Ubuntu 20.04のsystemdを使っているのですが、Requires指定における「依存ユニットの起動に失敗したら本ユニットも失敗する」が機能しなくて悩んでます。

```
# file:unitA.service
[Unit]
Description = Unit A
Requires = unitB.service
After = unitB.service

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/local/sbin/unitA
```

```
# file:unitB.service
[Unit]
Description = Unit B

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/local/sbin/unitB
```

とし、unitB側の実行時に確実にエラー終了する(戻り値1を返すスクリプト)ようにしているのですが、

```
$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
$ sudo systemctl stop unitA unitB # 一度両方を停止させておく
$ sudo systemctl start unitA # Aだけ起動、本当ならBがコケるのでAも失敗してくれるはず…?
$ sudo systemctl status unitA unitB --no-pager

● unitA.service - Unit A
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/unitA.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2020-06-01 05:56:00 JST; 1min 35s ago
   Main PID: 2657 (unitA)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1157)
     Memory: 632.0K
     CGroup: /system.slice/unitA.service
             └─2657 /bin/bash /usr/local/sbin/unitA

 6月 01 05:56:00 sl systemd[1]: Started Unit A.

● unitB.service - Unit B
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/unitB.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-06-01 05:56:00 JST; 1min 35s ago
    Process: 2656 ExecStart=/usr/local/sbin/unitB (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2656 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 6月 01 05:56:00 sl systemd[1]: Started Unit B.
 6月 01 05:56:00 sl systemd[1]: unitB.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 6月 01 05:56:00 sl systemd[1]: unitB.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

と、Bは失敗してるけどA側が動いてしまってます。
**Bが失敗してるときにAも起動できなくする** パラメーターは他にあったでしょうか?

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/266522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aが起動する理由は、Bの `Type=` が `simple` に設定されているため、 `unitB` が起動された瞬間にサービスの開始 (startup) が成功したとみなされるからです。実際に起こっていることは以下のとおりです：

1. `unitB` 正常にサービスが開始
2. `unitA` Bが開始したために開始
3. `unitB` サービス実行中に異常終了

あなたが書かれたような挙動を得るためには、サービスの開始が完了した時点を明示的に systemd に伝えるような `Type=` を `unitB` に指定する必要があります。 `Type=` による挙動の違いは `systemd.service(5)` のmanページに詳しく書かれていますが、この場合 `forking` か `notify` のどちらかになると思います。ただし、いずれを選んだにせよ、少しややこしい準備が必要になりますので、実際に使うサービスの実装に合わせて選ぶことになると思います。

Comment: なるほど、simpleの挙動という部分もかかってくるんですね。
もうしばらくsystemd.service(5)をよく読み込んでみたいと思います。 ちゃんと文章読めないというのはつらい…

Comment: マニュアルページには非常に細かく書いてありますが、大雑把に説明すると、 `Type=simple` はサービスの開始は常に成功、`Type=forking` はサービスが（昔のサービスのように）2段階の `fork` で起動されることを想定していて、中間のプロセスが終了したところでサービスの開始が完了、`Type=notify` はライブラリ関数 `sd_notify` を呼んでサービス開始完了を通知する、という感じです。